# Magento Unable to save custom order attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, php, attributes, orders, custom-attributes

I've create a custom module that create two custom attributes for the order.

**etc.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Companyname_modulename>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </Companyname_modulename>
  </modules>

  <global>
    <helpers>
      <modulename>
        <class>Companyname_modulename_Helper</class>
      </modulename>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <modulename>
          <class>Companyname_modulename_Model</class>
          <resourceModel>modulename_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </modulename>
    </models>
    <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote>                           
           <custom_field_one><to_order>*</to_order></custom_field_one>
        </sales_convert_quote>

        <sales_convert_order>                                              
            <custom_field_one><to_quote>*</to_quote></custom_field_one>
        </sales_convert_order>
    </fieldsets>
    <resources>
      <modulename_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Companyname_modulename</module>
          <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </modulename_setup>
      <modulename_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </modulename_write>
      <modulename_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </modulename_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

**SQL Script**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'custom_field_one', array(
    'type'            => 'varchar',
    'backend_type'    => 'varchar',
    'frontend_input'  => 'varchar',
    'is_user_defined' => true,
    'label'           => 'Custom Field One',
    'visible'         => true,
    'required'        => false,
    'user_defined'    => false,
    'searchable'      => false,
    'filterable'      => false,
    'comparable'      => false,
    'default'         => ''
));

$installer->addAttribute('quote', 'custom_filed_one', array(
    'type'            => 'varchar',
    'backend_type'    => 'varchar',
    'frontend_input'  => 'varchar',
    'is_user_defined' => true,
    'label'           => 'Custom Field One',
    'visible'         => true,
    'required'        => false,
    'user_defined'    => false,
    'searchable'      => false,
    'filterable'      => false,
    'comparable'      => false,
    'default'         => ''
));

$installer->addAttribute('order', 'custom_field_two', array(
    'type'            => 'varchar',
    'backend_type'    => 'varchar',
    'frontend_input'  => 'varchar',
    'is_user_defined' => true,
    'label'           => 'Custom Field Two',
    'visible'         => true,
    'required'        => false,
    'user_defined'    => false,
    'searchable'      => false,
    'filterable'      => false,
    'comparable'      => false,
    'default'         => ''
));

$installer->addAttribute('quote', 'custom_field_two', array(
    'type'            => 'varchar',
    'backend_type'    => 'varchar',
    'frontend_input'  => 'varchar',
    'is_user_defined' => true,
    'label'           => 'Custom Field Two',
    'visible'         => true,
    'required'        => false,
    'user_defined'    => false,
    'searchable'      => false,
    'filterable'      => false,
    'comparable'      => false,
    'default'         => ''
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Then when save a value into this two custom attributes the value not saving ex:

Load the quote by customer ID:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote') ->loadByCustomer($customerId);
```

Save value in custom attributes:

```
$quote->setCustomFieldOne("ValueOne");
$quote->setCustomFieldtwo("ValueTwo");
```

**The custom_field_one attribute is saved But the custom_filed_two attribute not saving any suggestions please?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's may be because you have spelt the field name incorrectly:

custom_**filed**_one

setCustom**Field**One()

```
 $installer->addAttribute('quote', 'custom_filed_one', array(....


 $quote->setCustomFieldOne("ValueOne");
```

ok so you said typo in comment, the next thing I would look at is your xml file.

If you're following this example:

https://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2014/03/03/how-to-create-new-attribute-to-order-in-magento/

then you haven't updated the fieldset in the xml to customfield instead of deliverydate.

Comment: it's spelt like above in my question

Comment: yes that is what I mean.  you two different spellings: filed and field.

Comment: Ah sorry this is a typo. All is Correct but it's not working.

Comment: ok, I have updated answer - I think it's the xml file issue, didn't notice before you haven't defined your custom fields - you are using the fields from the example.

Comment: That's right, my problem is in xml file, the second custom attribute not defined.

Comment: Glad I could assist :)